# Connecting 12 V RS485 appliance (soil sensor) to USB 5 V RS485 adaptor

Tags: power-supply, voltage, rs485, adapter

I have a 12 V RS485 appliance that measures some soil resistance etc. It is a [7-in-one soil sensor](https://khunsomsak.medium.com/7-in-1-soil-sensor-weiyun-com-ee8d55f927f4), the  12 V version of the 5 V version shown in the link.

I could not find a 12 V USB to RS485 adaptor with a 12 V output.

So what I did was: I used a 12 V DC power supply and connected the +VE
to the sensor's power input and then I shared the ground with the USB-to-RS485
adaptor.

Just wondering if this is correct. I still cannot get the sensor working.

Answer (score 0):

RS-485 does not use 12V signaling but 5V and USB devices like RS-485 adapters are powered with 5V from USB, not higher voltages.

So you likely won't find a USB RS-485 adapter that also includes a boost converter to 12V, if you want one you would need to design one yourself or at least add a 5V to 12V boost module to an existing cable.

So connecting RS-485 data pair and ground to RS-485 adapter and add a separate 12V supply to 12V input and ground is correct and should work.

Comment: Ya I could not get it to work but then again I found  this youtube video that IGNORES the ground.. I'll try that and see what happens. that is power the Sensor with 12volt power supply and supply only the A and B to the RS485 input.

https://youtu.be/FwKbfq1WYSM

Comment: Well, by definition, the RS-485 devices must share a common ground reference so that the common mode voltage is within acceptable limits. This common reference might be mains earth via power supplies, so in this case the device grounds may alredy be connected together to same common potential and thus separate common ground wire between devices is not necessary. It depends on the equipment, and it can't be ignored. An ungrounded mains supply can cause too much common mode voltage difference and prevent communicatons, and can even cause damage if the RS-485 transceiver chip can't handle it.

Comment: Hi I have finally gotten it to work..2 wire connection.... the device turned out to be simply taking RS485 commands and its responding at 9600 BAUD instead of the expected 4800.

I simply connected the device to a 12 Volt DC source to power it and connected the A B wires to the USB adaptor to the PC. Its able to communicate and respond.

So sharing ground is not needed.

Comment: Like I said, RS-485 needs a common ground reference to work reliably. There is no way around that. If your systen works without connecting the ground wire between devices, it means your system provides a common reference via connections to power supplies. Don't expect it to work if you later change the power supply to another one which makes the system to not work.